# Get index along specific axis for multidimensional slice in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have code like this:

```
import numpy as np    
b = np.random.choice([0, 1], size=(12, 10, 2), p=[0.5, 0.5]) > 0.5    
a = np.ones((12, 10, 2, 6, 4))

a = a[b]    
print(a.shape)
```

and I want to know which position along axis 1 (the 10 above) that each selection came from, e.g.,

a[0, 0, 0] = 0 (came from b[:, 0, :])

a[0, 0, 1] = 3 (came from b[:, 3, :])

a[6, 3, 1] = 1 (came from b[:, 1, :])

etc.

How can I do this?

Here's a simplified version without the randomized choice:

```
import numpy as np

b = np.array([[0, 1], [1, 1]]) > 0.5
a = np.array([[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[5, 6], [7, 8]]])

a = a[b] #gives [[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]]

# Desired result: 1,0,1 as each element came from that index of axis 1 of b

[1, 0, 1] # The index along the axis of the last dim of b for each selection in a
```

Comment: I took a good time reading your question and could not understand what you want... could you please clarify your post? What is your desired output given an example.

Comment: I added a more simple example. Let me know if this makes sense.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I still don't get it, sorry. So what you say in other words is that you want the index of your `True` values in `b` along the las axis of `b`? Say, in the simple example, you have `[[False, True],[True, True]]`, so the index of those `True`'s along the last dimension (just 2 in this case) ends up being `[1, 0, 1]` as they are in b[0,**1**] , b[1,**0**], and b[1, **1**]. Is this right?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Ok, then I will edit the question to reflect that more clearly, and then remove the DV :) I will also post an answer shortly. Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and I want to know which position along axis 1 (the 10 above) that each selection came from, ...

As you are executing `a = a[b]` then the new elements of `a` will be those related to the `True` values that were in your randomized `b` array. For that, you can use the `numpy.where()`  [method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) on `b` to know which ones where those, something like this:

```
import numpy as np

b = np.random.choice([0, 1], size=(12, 10, 2), p=[0.5, 0.5]) > 0.5 #random choice
a = np.ones((12, 10, 2, 6, 4))

a = a[b] #obtain those randomly selected items
print(a.shape)

indexes = np.where(b==True)
print(indexes[1]) #the axis 1 you desire
```

Note that if you wish to get *other* `b` axis (say axis `i`) you should get that like `indexes[i]`. Also note that this will give different values each time, as it is randomized.

However, testing it with your simpler example we also get the desired `[1,0,1]`:

```
import numpy as np
b = np.array([[0, 1], [1, 1]]) > 0.5
a = np.array([[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[5, 6], [7, 8]]])

a = a[b] #gives result [[3,4], [5,6], [7,8]], so they are 1,0,1
print(a.shape) #gives (3, 2)

indexes = np.where(b==True)
print(indexes[1]) #gives us the desired 1,0,1
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. I'm traveling at the very moment, but look forward to giving this a try. Thank you!

Comment: Ok @jstaker7 , let me know if it helps, I am certain it will probably...